# Accidentally imported trash folder into project

Tags: macos, atom-editor, root

I accidentally deleted my index.html file instead of my selected line of code.  Dragging the file back into Atom imported the entire .trash folder.  I thought, well, I can't take out a root directory, but I've deleted the content within before.  I can live with that. 
 Of course, whatever I deleted came straight back to trash!!  Is there any way to fix this or will I have to transfer everything to a new project and burn this one?